# Jest: Setup URL and check variable

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom, jestjs

So, it's my first and exciting day with Jest, this is my vanilla "foo.html" file, no React, no Vue:

```
<html>
<head><title>Hello Jest!</title></head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var hasFoo = false;
   if (window.location.href.indexOf("foo") != -1) {
     hasFoo = true;
   }
   console.log(" hasFoo > ", hasFoo);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to create the Jest test like:

```
const html = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './foo.html'), 'utf8');
document.documentElement.innerHTML = html.toString();
```

but I'm stuck, my questions are:

1. How can I setup the URL to put a "foo" substring in it?
2. How can I access and check the "hasFoo" variable in the Jest test?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) to interact with the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction).

Answer to question 1:

You should set URL for JSDOM.

> `url`: sets the value returned by window.location, document.URL, and document.documentURI, and affects things like resolution of relative URLs within the document and the same-origin restrictions and referrer used while fetching subresources. It defaults to "about:blank".

Answer to question 2:

The global variable `hasFoo` is attached to the `window` object. You can get it from the `window` object.

Besides:

1. In order to execute scripts, you need to use `runScripts: "dangerously"` option.
2. Add snapshot testing for testing the structure of DOM.
3. In order to test if the `console.log` is to be called or not, you need to use `jest.spyOn(console, 'log')` statement to create spy on `console.log` method and use [Virtual consoles](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#virtual-consoles)

Complete example:

`foo.html`:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello Jest!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var hasFoo = false;
      if (window.location.href.indexOf('foo') != -1) {
        hasFoo = true;
      }
      console.log(' hasFoo > ', hasFoo);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`foo.test.js`:

```js
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

describe('64975712', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const html = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './foo.html'), 'utf8');
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    const virtualConsole = new jsdom.VirtualConsole();
    virtualConsole.sendTo(console);
    const dom = new JSDOM(html, {
      url: 'http://foo.exmaple.org',
      virtualConsole,
      runScripts: 'dangerously',
    });
    expect(dom.window).toHaveProperty('hasFoo');
    expect(dom.window.hasFoo).toBeTruthy();
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith(' hasFoo > ', true);
    expect(dom.serialize()).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
      "<html><head>
          <title>Hello Jest!</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <script type=\\"text/javascript\\">
            var hasFoo = false;
            if (window.location.href.indexOf('foo') != -1) {
              hasFoo = true;
            }
            console.log(' hasFoo > ', hasFoo);
          </script>
        

      </body></html>"
    `);
    logSpy.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/64975712/foo.test.js
  64975712
    ✓ should pass (36ms)

  console.log node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:866
     hasFoo >  true

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
Time:        5.067s
```